# How to convert an entire hyper Response, including the headers and all the parts, into bytes?

Tags: http, rust, hyper

How to convert a [`hyper::Response`](https://docs.rs/hyper/1.0.0-rc.1/hyper/struct.Response.html) object into the bytes that would be sent over the network for it, including all parts of the response (the status code, version, headers, and body)?

Comment: That's a rather unusual thing to need. What's the use case?

Comment: For HTTP/1.1, check out Server::encode: https://docs.rs/hyper/latest/src/hyper/proto/h1/role.rs.html#341. There's a bit of finagling to convert a Response into a suitable Encode object.

Comment: @tadman it's a sort of an HTTP proxy that takes HTTP requests, executes them in a different network using a local client, and sends the responses back to the original browser. So we have a client running in the local network of the server and we need to send back the response and and then transmit it back to the original browser. It's all part of an [upcoming feature](https://github.com/metalbear-co/mirrord/issues/290) in [mirrord](https://github.com/metalbear-co/mirrord).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with for now:

```
    async fn response_to_bytes(response: Response<Full<Bytes>>) -> Vec<u8> {
        let (
            response::Parts {
                status,
                version,
                headers,
                extensions: _, // TODO: should we be using this?
                ..
            },
            body,
        ) = response.into_parts();

        // Enough for body + headers of length 64 each + 64 bytes for status line.
        // This will probably be more than enough most of the time.
        let mut bytes =
            BytesMut::with_capacity(body.size_hint().lower() as usize + 64 * headers.len() + 64);

        let version = match version {
            Version::HTTP_09 => "HTTP/0.9",
            Version::HTTP_10 => "HTTP/1.0",
            Version::HTTP_11 => "HTTP/1.1",
            Version::HTTP_2 => "HTTP/2",
            Version::HTTP_3 => "HTTP/3",
            _ => "HTTP/1.1", // TODO: handle this case.
        };

        // Status line.
        bytes.put(version.as_bytes()); // HTTP/1.1
        bytes.put(&b" "[..]);
        bytes.put(status.as_str().as_bytes()); // 200
        bytes.put(&b" "[..]);
        if let Some(reason) = status.canonical_reason() {
            bytes.put(reason.as_bytes()); // OK
        } else {
            bytes.put(&b"LOL"[..]); // TODO: ?
        }

        // Headers.
        for (name, value) in headers.into_iter() {
            if let Some(name) = name {
                bytes.put(&b"\r\n"[..]);
                bytes.put(name.as_str().as_bytes());
                bytes.put(&b": "[..]);
            } else {
                // TODO: are multiple values for the same header comma delimited?
                bytes.put(&b","[..])
            }
            bytes.put(value.as_bytes())
        }
        bytes.put(&b"\r\n\r\n"[..]);

        // Body.
        bytes.put(body.collect().await.unwrap().to_bytes()); // Unwrap Infallible.

        bytes.to_vec()
    }
```